# How to fit different size images in my grid CSS Layo

Tags: html, css

This is my code.

I have multiple images.
They have different sizes.
How can I fit then to my divs and maintain this grid layout?

Should I fix width and height and use what property in css?

- PS: needs to be a CSS solution.

Any help guys?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  columns: 18rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  counter-reset: grid;
}

.item + .item {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.item {
  break-inside: avoid;
  aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
  background: pink;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
}

.item::before {
  counter-increment: grid;
  content: counter(grid);
}

.item:nth-child(3n) {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: lavender;
}

.item:nth-child(3n - 1) {
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 3;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*added code starts */
.similarDiv{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
gap: 2rem;

}
.similarDiv > img{
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
object-position: center;
display: block;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.similarDiv > img:hover{
box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
transform: translateY(-5px)
}

/*added code ends */

.grid {
  columns: 18rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  counter-reset: grid;
}

.item + .item {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}


.item {
  break-inside: avoid;
  aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
  background: pink;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/23/300/330');
  background-size: cover;
}

.item::before {
  counter-increment: grid;
  content: counter(grid);
}

.item:nth-child(3n) {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: lavender;
}

.item:nth-child(3n - 1) {
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 3;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="similarDiv">
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/23/500/400" />
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/24/500/400" />
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/25/500/400" />
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/26/500/400" />
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/27/500/400" />
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/28/500/400" />
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/29/500/400" />
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/30/500/400" />
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/31/500/400" />
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks for your time! Basically is to add images inside of a div background right? This is how the image "fits" the divs